# Same date from database use a different UTC Offeset from Backend to Frontend

Tags: node.js, date, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have some problem with a date getted from MySQL Database

Once I extract the date I do a console.log on the server:

```
console.log('Original Date: ', dip.nato_il);
console.log('Formatted Date: ', moment(dip.nato_il).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log('UTC Offset: ', moment(dip.nato_il).utcOffset());
```

and this is the log result:

```
Original Date:  1961-09-07T22:00:00.000Z
Formatted Date:  1961-09-08
UTC Offset:  120
```

So the value of utfOffset is correct for me and the formated date too.

After this console.log I send to frontend the data  with res.send() of express and I log the same date on Chrome console and this is the result of log:

```
Original Date:  1961-09-07T22:00:00.000Z
Formatted Date:  1961-09-07
UTC Offset:  60
```

I don't understood why is this change of offset, only with this date, for example another date give me this results on beckend:

```
Original Date:  1990-08-18T22:00:00.000Z
Formatted Date:  1990-08-19
UTC Offset:  120
```

and this on Frontend:

```
Original Date:  1990-08-18T22:00:00.000Z
Formatted Date:  1990-08-19
UTC Offset:  120
```

I try to log this in Chrome console too:

```
console.log('1961 ---> ', moment('1961-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1961 --->  60"
console.log('1962 ---> ', moment('1962-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1962 --->  60"
console.log('1963 ---> ', moment('1963-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1963 --->  60"
console.log('1964 ---> ', moment('1964-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1964 --->  60"
console.log('1965 ---> ', moment('1965-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1965 --->  60"
console.log('1966 ---> ', moment('1966-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1966 --->  120"
console.log('1967 ---> ', moment('1967-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1967 --->  120"
console.log('1968 ---> ', moment('1968-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1968 --->  120"
console.log('1969 ---> ', moment('1969-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1969 --->  120"
console.log('1970 ---> ', moment('1970-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1970 --->  120"
console.log('1971 ---> ', moment('1971-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1971 --->  120"
console.log('1972 ---> ', moment('1972-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1972 --->  120"
console.log('1973 ---> ', moment('1973-09-07T22:00:00.000Z').utcOffset());  // Log result "1973 --->  120"
```

Why with some date get just 1 hour instead of 2?

The server is NodeJs based, with Express like routing framework, for get the data from DB I use ObjectioJs with knexJs. Moment is the node module used for manage the date.
The server is in Frankfurt, and I'm in Italy, so the timezone is the same.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locale, Italy, started observing Daylight Savings Time in 1966.  Accordingly, the timezone offset for dates in September changed in that year.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/italy/rome?year=1960

The [zoneinfo](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) data, embedded in moment-timezone and other places, contains a surprising amount of temporopolitical history.